# mysql distinct with other things too

Tags: php, mysql

This should be very simple, but I cannot find the correct syntax using search.

I have:

```sql
SELECT distinct name, id FROM table1 WHERE length<6;
```

I want to return the id's and names of all distinct names (not distinct ids, since thats an auto increment anyway), but this query is currently returning all names and ids, not just the distinct names...

What's the correct way to do this?

Edit: Length is another columns name and not relevant specifically here.

Comment: What are you expecting with the "length < 6" qualifier... length of a name, is it another column in the table, or just 6 distinct names where you would otherwise just be using a "LIMIT 6"

Comment: so if you had a ID=1 with name 'john smith' and an ID=7 with name 'john smith' you would want to see john smith once... would you care what ID is returned?  Lets be more precise... So if using the above the following were returned would it be acceptable:  7 john smith.  Even though there is also a 1 john smith

Comment: @drapp - it is another column. @ xQbert - the first id to appear in the table for that name...

Comment: Then either ypercube's 3rd  or Michael's responses should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want distinct names, and *any* associated id.  `DISTINCT` will return distinct rows as combinations of the selected columns, and since `id` is auto-increment, that means all rows.  Instead use an aggregate.

This query will return the name, and the first auto-increment `id` with it:

```
SELECT
  name, 
  MIN(id) as id
FROM table1
WHERE length < 6
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: @xQbert: OP commented: *"it is another column..."*

Comment: @ypercube not at the time I had posted.  but I fixed it since it was w/in 5 min :D

Answer (score 2):

Distinct names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM table1 
WHERE length < 6
```

Distinct names and all their ids:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
FROM table1 
WHERE length < 6
GROUP BY name
```

Distinct names and the lowest id:

```
SELECT name, MIN(id)              --- or MAX(id) for the highest id
FROM table1 
WHERE length < 6
GROUP BY name
```

Distinct names and a (more or less) random id (this works in MySQL only and no other DBMS):

```
SELECT name, id            
FROM table1 
WHERE length < 6
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: But I still want to return the id column value that goes with each distinct name...

Comment: So, what if a `name` has many `id`? Which one should be selected?

Comment: ah I see...good question.  Now I understand why mysql does not like it.  I guess the id of the first instance of that name?

Comment: Michael has it (as does this post 3rd answer. (Though I like all the reasons behind this post so + 1 here too)

Answer (score 0):

select id, name from table1 as t0 join
( select distinct name from table1 ) as t1 
on t0.name = t1.name;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean

```
where length(name) < 6
```